# How do define the height using percentage?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I am trying to create a website that requires fluid re-sizing. How ever the positioning does not seem to work for the "top" or "bottom" when I use %. It works fine when I use px or em.

i am trying to position the slider of a jquery showcase called flexslider 2. it is a div element that is linked to two images. an example of the original html can be found here at the bottom. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

```
<div style="padding:5px;">
    <div class="flexslider">
         <ul class="slides">
             <li><img src="images/ussc1.jpg" alt="01" /></li>
             <li><img src="images/ussc2.jpg" alt="02" /></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css.

```
.flexslider { 
    max-width:940px; 
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 20%; 
    position:absolute; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help! I do apologise in advance, i am very new to web design

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling of "postion", should be:

```
.flexslider{
    position:absolute;
}
```

If the position isn't specified properly the "top" and "bottom" styles won't work with percentages!

Comment: Hello! thank you for your response. but that was just a typo when i transferred the code. the spelling is correct in my actual code.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried it in a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zTpKX/ and it seems to be working fine for me... There might be some other code you have that is making this a problem.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you find it.